# Render javascript (or css) via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I want to execute the javascript below via C# for a Sharepoint-2010 page. What is the best way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  document.getElementById("LeftNavigationAreaCell").style.display="none";     
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you access the `Response` object? What about a `ScriptManager`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in sharepoint but the [ScripManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) class is used to do this kind of things in WebPages, Check the `RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock` Methods

Hope it helps...